# Altair documentation example not working due to a Javascript Error

Tags: python, runtime-error, altair, code-documentation

The following code block comes entirely from Altair documentation, it's one of the [example graphs](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/us_population_over_time.html).

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.population.url

select_year = alt.selection_point(
    name="Year",
    fields=["year"],
    bind=alt.binding_range(min=1900, max=2000, step=10, name="Year"),
    value={"year": 2000},
)

alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X("sex:N", axis=alt.Axis(labels=False, title=None, ticks=False)),
    y=alt.Y("people:Q", scale=alt.Scale(domain=(0, 12000000)), title="Population"),
    color=alt.Color(
        "sex:N",
        scale=alt.Scale(domain=("Male", "Female"), range=["steelblue", "salmon"]),
        title="Sex",
    ),
    column=alt.Column("age:O", title="Age"),
).properties(
    width=20,
    title="U.S. Population by Age and Sex"
).add_params(
    select_year
).transform_calculate(
    "sex", alt.expr.if_(alt.datum.sex == 1, "Male", "Female")
).transform_filter(
    select_year
).configure_facet(
    spacing=8
)
```

Even though it's an official example, on my machine it results in an error:

```
Javascript Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
This usually means there's a typo in your chart specification. See the javascript console for the full traceback.
```

I'm running this in JupyterLab v3.4.4 in Chrome, macOS 12.6, conda with altair v5.0.1. This graph uses `alt.selection_point` which was only added in altair v5. Other graphs are displaying just fine.

I originally ran this as part of a different notebook, but later created a new notebook on a same kernel and pasted **ONLY** this example there, no other code.

Why could this be happening?

Comment: No reference, but it displayed correctly in my environment. Windows11,jupyterLab:4.0.2,altair:5.01

Comment: @r-beginners you won't believe it - updating to jupyterlab 4.0.2 worked! thank you very much, for some reason the jupyter version completely slipped my mind. It's interesting how you forget such basic things.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Went from jupyterlab >3.6.x to 4.0.x and the issue was resolved (in VS code + notebooks on Mac with altair 5.0.1)

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, it was the JupyterLab version. Updating to version 4.0.2 resolved the issue. I'm an idiot :D

Edit: Actually, the issue still occurs sometimes. I have no clue why, don't see any correlation with my actions.